# Axios: use same interceptor with multiple axios instances

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

In my code base there are various Axios instances created using

```js
axios.create()
```

because there are multiple base URLs used in my app. So per baseURL we have created a corresponding Axios instance.

Now in App.js file, I have included 2 interceptors

1. request interceptor
2. response interceptor

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(
        config => {
          return config;
        },
        error => {          
          if (error && error.response.status === 401) {
              signOut();
          }
          return Promise.reject(error);
        }
      );
```

But all the API calls are by-passing the above-mentioned 2 interceptors.

### Problem:

I want to use the above-mentioned interceptors as the Global interceptors for all the Axios instances in my project.

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/993

Answer (score 9):

**First Option - "Easier"**

Just create your own "axios generator" function.

```
const createAxios = (baseURL) => {
   const newInstance = axios.create({ baseURL });

   newInstance.interceptors.response.use(
      (config) => config,
      (error) => {
        if (error && error.response.status === 401) {
          signOut();
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );

    return newInstance;
}
```

**Second Option - More Complicated**
Personally I prefer this option, as I find it more tidy, and logically separated and divided (each "entity" stands by itself).

What i would probably do is create a BasicService Class which would look something like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

class BasicService {
  constructor(url) {
    const options = {
      baseURL: url,
      // any options that you would want for all axios requests,
      // like (proxy, etc...)
    };
    
    this.fetcher = axios.create(options);

    // Your default config
    this.fetcher.interceptors.response.use(
      (config) => {
        return config;
      },
      (error) => {
        if (error && error.response.status === 401) {
          signOut();
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

then for each axios instance i would like to create, i would also create a class with all fetches. like:

```
const baseURL= '/users';

class UserService extends BasicService {
  // GET Requests
  async GetAll() {
    return (await this.fetcher.get('/all')).data;
  }

  // POST Requests
  async insertUser(userToInsert) {
    return await this.fetcher.post(...)
  }
}

const userService = new UserService(baseURL);

export default userService;
```

then in any file i would just import my wanted service and fetch it

```
import UserService from "/services/UserService";
UserService.getAll().then(...);
```

This helps you keep the same config for all axios instances while keeping your code as generic and clean as possible

Comment: Hi, I like the second option and trying to implement in my project. However I need to add auth token to header using interceptor after user login. How would you recommend doing this?

Comment: Well you can edit the base request interceptor if it works for every request. If it's required only for a subclass, you can implement a new constructor which calls `super(url)` (to set up the initial `fetcher` instance) and then add you own custom request interceptors to set your Authorization headers (using `this.fetcher.interceptors.request.use` which is accessible from any subclass).

Comment: Thanks. Since I need to add the token **after** user login, and all instances are already created, and you don't instantiate the `BasicService` right? Or do you mean that I can add interceptors to any instance of any subclass? For example if I added the interceptor to `userService` (`userService.fetcher.interceptors.request.use`), it will be applied to all subclasses inherited from the same class (`BasicService`)?

Comment: Depends on your use case, I suggest you create a service for requests that do not require an Auth header, use it to authenticate and obtain the credentials, and then init a new Service which accepts credentials in it's constructor and sets the appropriate headers. This way your code is more robust as you do not require to mutate your services but just Initiate a new service for It's specific use case and logical goal, and use it whenever required

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interceptor function and then use them with the instances that you want.

```
  const commonErrorInterceptor = (error: any) => {
    // Do something with the error (e.g., handle specific error codes, show error messages, etc.)
    let responseError: responseErrorInterface;
    if (error.response.status === STATUS_CODES.BAD_REQUEST) {
      responseError = {
        status: error.response.status,
        code: error.response.data.errors.code,
        message: error.response.data.errors.message,
      };
    } else {
      responseError = {
        status: error.response.status,
        code: 0,
        message: error.response.message,
      };
    }
    return Promise.reject(responseError);
  };
```

is used with different axios instances :

```
 fetcher.interceptors.response.use(
    commonResponseInterceptor,
    commonErrorInterceptor,
  );
  fetcherWithJWT.interceptors.response.use(
    commonResponseInterceptor,
    commonErrorInterceptor,
  );
  fetcherWithCredentials.interceptors.response.use(
    commonResponseInterceptor,
    commonErrorInterceptor,
  );
```